# I want to verify checkout process through Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to perform checkout process for an e-commerce site using JMeter for 50 users. I am doing it by recording screen and by adding 50 users in thread groups. I want to know that does the item added to the cart while actually recording the screen get added in the cart for fifty Jmeter users? plus I get an email after placing an order so will I get the email for 50 users while doing it with Jmeter?
PS: I am not getting any such thing actually so I want to know how can I verify that Jmeter is doing it for 50 users when I am not receiving any email (On order placing) and the records do not get set in the database.

Please help me out in knowing it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As per [4 Things You Should Never Do with Your JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-never-do-your-jmeter-script) guide:

> **2. Don’t run the script exactly as you recorded it**
>
> After recording your script, there is still some work to do before you run it. It’s necessary to correlate variables, parameterize and add elements, to faithfully simulate users.
>
> Here is a short list of general samplers and modifications that you’ll need to consider:
>
> - Add a [Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) - pay attention whether you need to erase the cookies on each iteration or not (you can set this with a checkbox in the sampler).
> - Add a [HTTP Request Default](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) Sampler to define the server, port and protocol in just one place. If you erase this specification from your requests, you will be able to change your test environment easier.
> - Review which [Response Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) you need to add.
> - Parametrize Hosts in the [Headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to make your script more flexible and supportable.

So don't run all 50 users unless you are sure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing, run your test with 1 virtual user and carefully inspect request and response details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. If you see something weird, i.e. login page instead of checkout page, you will need to amend the corresponding request.

Comment: thanks for responding. What actually you are referring to correlate as in my case I don't think anything needs to be correlated. So can you please guide me what for the general e-com site things can be correlated in such scenario?
Plus I am using this listener and I am getting correct response but I want to behave it as an actual user as happens in BOTS?

Answer (score 0):

Since from your question, it is like your script is working fine and you are receiving email notification too.

1. The first way to verify is by querying in DB and using an assertion. If your data in DB is as expected per operation then you are on the right track.
2. Second, you can log in to your email and verify (click [HERE](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url) for more details.

Comment: Hey thanks, buddy!! no, I am not receiving any email from the script. I received only email when I actually performed the whole process while running the script through Jmeter and increasing number of users I didn't receive any email.

Comment: do you receive an email from a single user? if so then, your configuration should be fine. 
if you are not receiving an email from multiple users then possible scenarios are:
1.you need to check your spam folder OR
2.there may be some handling in your code base.consult with your dev about this OR

Just try to increase the number of a user manually and find the threshold. I think there is something in your code base.